# Is it possible / how to get last commit of copy of some remote in local repository?

Tags: git, logging

I try:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H --remotes=upstream/master
```

but it returns last commit from another branch and another remote

if I do

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H --remotes=upstream
```

it returned me commit from when / where I forked this repository...

added another example:

```
>git fetch upstream master
From git://github.com/fsharp/fsharp
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

>git ls-remote upstream master
81c94470de1587902a20f40741388e361dc09690        refs/heads/master

>git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H upstream/master
2898aa10ec5022fdfb79e5c3a6350d58737964cc

>git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H FETCH_HEAD
1c94470de1587902a20f40741388e361dc09690
```

Comment: Not really sure what you want to do but if you want to look at the remote branch history you simply specify the remote without `--remotes` option (this is used for quite different things).

Comment: What git version do you have?

Comment: @VonC git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1

Comment: it seems like fetch doesn't save anything in local copy... but change FETCH_HEAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surest way remains to fetch that remote first:

```
git add aremote /url/of/that/remo
git fetch aremote
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H aremote/master
```

You can check if FETCH_HEAD is at least at the right SHA1

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H FETCH_HEAD
```

If it is, then check if you don't have a tag named '`upstream/master`' which would "shadow" the refs '`upstream/master`'.

The [OP Heather](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238232/heather) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868055/is-it-possible-how-to-get-last-commit-of-copy-of-some-remote-in-local-reposito/23869489?noredirect=1#comment36741984_23869489) getting the right SHA1 with:

```
git merge-base master upstream/master
```

Comment: please check question update, they are not the same.

Comment: I don't need to check FETCH_HEAD because I'm interesting in situation when local and remote will be different so then I will update...

Comment: @Heather I understand that. Can you still check what `FETCH_HEAD` contains? Just to be sure. As a test.

Comment: @Heather strange, FETCH_HEAD is equal to upstream master except for the first digit.

Comment: it's just my fault of copy/paste but FETCH_HEAD is not what I want because it's just last fetch, not related to remote or branch

Comment: Can you test that with the latest msysgit 1.9.1? You don't have to iverwrite your current setup, you can just unzip a 1.9.1 release elsewhere and try with that msysgit. (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/download/Git-1.9.2-preview20140411/PortableGit-1.9.2-preview20140411.7z)

Comment: I think I've found the solution. I can use `git merge-base`

Comment: @Heather how did you used `git merge-base`?

Comment: `git merge-base master upstream/master`

Comment: @Heather Ok, I have included it in the answer for more visibility. It is almost as if that branch was forced pushed (with a different history than the one you have locally)